# Seeking well-commented versions of mgcv source code

Tags: r, open-source, mgcv

**Apologies for cross-posting (on R-help)** but SO gets more views, and I hope someone who knows might find the question here.

I'm looking for well-commented versions of various functions comprising mgcv, so that I can modify a piece of it for a project I'm working on.  In particular I'm looking for

- testStat
- summary.gam
- liu2
- simf

I know that I can find these by typing mgcv:::whatever.  But there are a lot of nested `if` statements, making it difficult to follow. Comments in the code describing exactly what is happening at each step would make my life a lot easier.

Where can I find more-detailed versions of the code?  Do such things exist?

**EDIT**:
In response to the deleted comment:  I didn't know that it could be found on github, not having used it before.  FFR, it's here:  https://github.com/cran/mgcv

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you searched GitHub for any of the source code? There is commented code there.  I found `testStat` in [the **mgcv.r** file](https://github.com/cran/mgcv/blob/master/R/mgcv.r).

---

**Here are a couple of suggestions that help me understand complex code:**

(1) Write the source to a text file so you can space it out, move things around, etc.

```
> sink("testStat.txt")
> mgcv:::testStat
> sink()
```

(2) Break its `body` into a list of its parts

```
> x <- as.list(body(mgcv:::testStat))
> x
[[1]]
`{`

[[2]]
qrx <- qr(X, tol = 0)

 ...

[[19]]
if (nu > 0) {
    if (k1 == 1) 
        rank1 <- val <- 1
    else {
        val <- rep(1, k1)
        rp <- nu + 1
        val[k] <- (rp + sqrt(rp * (2 - rp)))/2
        val[k1] <- (rp - val[k])
    }
    if (res.df <= 0) 
        pval <- liu2(d, val)
    else pval <- simf(d, val, res.df)
} else {
    pval <- 2
}

 ...

[[21]]
list(stat = d, pval = min(1, pval), rank = rank)
```

Comment: Note that you don't need to search `github`. you can simply use the `package source` from CRAN.

Comment: @mnel, is it commented?  Is that the code that's in some of my lib path files?

Comment: The `github/cran` repository is reading these files (as an unofficial mirror). Code will only be commented if the code submitted to cran is commented (which is not a cran requirement)